# Javascript onKeyPress key code always 0 on Android

Tags: javascript, android, validation, cordova, input

I am creating a cordova application which supports blackberry and Android. I have a function that responds to onKeyPress() to listen for when the user has pressed enter - to submit a search.

However on android the key code always return 0 regardless of character pressed.

Is this a bug or not supported within android?

Or is there a way around this issue?

Code below. I have tried - onkeydown - onkeypress - onkeyup

```
<input id="input_search_person" type="search" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search by Name or Company Name" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" onkeyup="didTapReturn(this)" />

function didTapReturn(e) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if (key == 13 && document.activeElement === e) {
        searchPerson();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me on galaxy s5

Comment: is that just return or all keycodes? Android version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also the same issue. Its with Android bug.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/update.do?id=68284#makechanges

Comment: You are welcome. They have updated webview component. Now you can use your onKeyPress()